# Create an array from arrays that holds data

Tags: php, array-merge, array-filter

I am trying to create an array that will hold the only array that contains values.

Code below works well, but I get trouble if for ex, $array2 (but can array1 or array3) doesn't contain any value. In that case, I need to merge only array1 and array3.

```
$array3 = array_filter( array_map( function( $term ) {
    if ( ! $term = \Softing\Term::get( $term ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    return [
        'link' => $term->get_link(),
        'name' => $term->get_name(),
        'color' => $term->get_color(), 
        ]; 


}, $terms ) );


$formatted_terms[] = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);
```

Each if three arrays are formed on the same way as  $array3, but some of them could be empty, no values. Those Arrays I dont want to merge. Want to create array only from arrays that holds value.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this.

I tried using

```
$formatted_terms[] = array_merge((array)$array1, (array)$array2, (array)$array3);
```

Any advice ?

Comment: _What is the easiest way to accomplish this._ No idea what you are trying to ask unless you show us example of input and expected ouput

Comment: @Marko did you have multiple arrays $array1,$array2,$array3,$array4?. Where are the $array1 - $array4 from (parent array)?. If it is from single array we can use loop.

Comment: I have updated question @B001ᛦ

Comment: @DroidDev Please check question now, I posted how I form arrays

Comment: There is no problem if one of the arrays is empty. Another thing is if one of the arrays is undefined or is not an array.

Comment: @Marko please check my answer, need to check if the arrays has values before merging. If the arrays are from single array you need to loop and merge

Comment: @ZhiV it will create warning like this `Argument is not an array `

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_filter()` to remove empty array values. Since you have a multidimensional array, you may consider using `array_map()` in conjunction with `array_filter()`.

Take the following for example:

```
$array1 = ['link'=>'foo', 'name'=>'bar', 'filter'=>'hello world'];

$array2 = false;

$array3 = ['link'=>'foo', 'name'=>'bar', 'filter'=>'hello world'];

$formatted_terms[] = array_merge((array)$array1, (array)$array2, (array)$array3);

$formatted_terms = array_map('array_filter',$formatted_terms);

echo '<pre>',print_r($formatted_terms),'</pre>';
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: I need to get at the end array, which I use to print out all values $formatted_terms[] , it doesnt work like this

Answer (score 0):

Just check if theyre an array and if theyre not empty. If so, use array merge. If not, just do nothing.

```
$a_all_arrays = array($array1, $array2, $array3);
$a_merged     = array();
foreach($a_all_arrays as $arr) 
{
    if(is_array($arr) && !is_empty($arr)) 
    {
        $a_merged = array_merge($a_merged, $arr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the array if it has values before merging,

```
$array1=!empty($array1) && is_array($array1)?$array1:[];
$array2=!empty($array2) && is_array($array2)?$array2:[];
$array3=!empty($array3) && is_array($array3)?$array3:[];
$formatted_terms[] = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);
```

Comment: Does that really make any sense?

Comment: Why not, if $array2 has a empty value in it.

Comment: _Why not, if $array2 has a string in it..._ If it contains string then it is not empty

Comment: empty variable\

Comment: An empty variable? What is that? However your code is just saying: if array is empty then array is empty, if not so then it is not empty... Makes no sense